# Should one include grants that were not finished on the CV?

Tags: funding, cv

If one gets a grant, and by some reason (e.g., administration problems with the university) the project needs to be ended before the grant is over. Should one list such grant in the CV? or just let it go into oblivion?

If put it into the CV is OK, then should one state that the grant ended before its time? or even state the reasons?

Answer (score 9):

The main reason to include a grant on a CV is to show that you can get a grant, which you did. Whether or not you made productive use of the grant is generally measured from the publications arising from the grant. You can provide explanations, if necessary, in accompanying letters -- a CV does not contain explanations, it just lists the essential facts.

Answer (score 4):

To add to @user6726's great answer, I would further say that in what I've seen CVs just list the basics of the grant: funding agency, agency grant ID, title, date range, amount, and the role of the CV author in the grant, i.e. PI or co-PI. Often, people also list that they were part of the writing team of a large-scale or important grant even if they were not among the PIs in order to emphasize significant participation where agency regulations do not allow them to be otherwise included*. I rarely see the papers coming from a grant tied to that grant's listing in the CV or vice-versa. Each of the papers will individually acknowledge the funding source, but they are usually not tied together in the CV.

In your situation, I would list the grant with the amount that was awarded (not spent) and the date range that it was active with no further explanation unless it was killed by the funding agency. If it was, you might offer an explanation if you can keep it short. Otherwise, if someone asks about a grant performance period that looks short, you can wait until then to explain it.

*: NSF allows 5 people to be listed as PI/co-PI, but several of our grants have included more significant writers than that.